# How to automatically add data to a Bound DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have a form of a DataGridView that would take only one column entry from users, which is the Name column. The DateCreated (the second column) will be automatically entered by the system, so once a user want to enter a new name and presses enter, the DateCreated is automatically filled.

The data in the form is generated from a DataTable, and the DataTable content is in turn generated from a database. The thing is that the DateCreated columns is designed not to take null values, so when the DataSet was created the same constraint was enforced in the DataTable.

Can anyone please help with how to intercept the data in the DataGridView before it gets to the DataTable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are callback functions you can hook up to the dependency property.  make a dependency property as data buffer, hook up validation module using those callback functions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795.aspx#Coerce_Value_Callbacks_and_Property_Changed_Events

Comment: I just looked into it - it seems it's WPF specific. I'm developing a WIndows Form app. Do you think there's a work around? And I'm using Framework 4.

Comment: oh shoot, I didn't look carefully on the tags you added, sorry. When I looked at c# DataGridView, I see CellValueChanged or ColumnAdded. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx  Maybe you can do event handler before passing to DataTable.

Comment: @ JP_medevice: Thanks again. I've been thinking event handler way too. I'll have to put that down as I've already decided to work on other aspects.